# DataGrid Dojo Not Working in Widget

Tags: dojo, widget, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a widget on dojo, but it does not display the datagrid. If I make the example outside the widget works. I see the code by firebug, you can not mistake, however, I can see the div inspect and there is nothing inside. The Builder runs, but does not load the grid in div.

Widget.js

```
define([ "dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/text!./FormularioQCI.html",
"icm/base/_BaseWidget",
"dojo/store/JsonRest",
"dojo/store/Memory",
"dojo/store/Cache",
"dojox/grid/DataGrid",
"dojo/data/ObjectStore"
],

function(declare, template, _BaseWidget, JsonRest, Memory, Cache, DataGrid, ObjectStore){
return declare("icm.custom.pgwidget.formularioQCI.FormularioQCIWidget", [_BaseWidget], {
templateString: template,
widgetsInTemplate: true,

constructor: function(){
    alert("X");
    myStore = dojo.store.Cache(dojo.store.JsonRest({target:"rest/formularioQCI/get"}), dojo.store.Memory());
    grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        store: dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),
        structure: [
            {name:"State Name", field:"name", width: "200px"},
            {name:"Abbreviation", field:"abbreviation", width: "200px", editable: true}
        ]
    }, "target-node-id"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
    grid.startup();
    alert("Y");
    dojo.query("#save").onclick(function(){
        alert("X");
        dataStore.save();
    });
    var id = 0;
    dojo.query("#add").onclick(function(){
        dataStore.newItem({
            name: "col2-" + id,
            abbreviation: "col3-" + id
        });
        id++;
    });
},

/**
 * @private destroys this widget
 */
destroy: function() {
    //Do any custom clean up here
    this.inherited(arguments);
}
});});
```

Widget.html

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
   <div id="target-node-id">
   </div>
   <button id="save">Save
   </button>
   <button id="add">Add Linha
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The code only shows the definition of the widget. How are  you instantiating the widget? You need to instantiate the widget. e.g `var mywidget = new MyWidgetClass()` where MyWidgetClass is the definition of the widget. Also you need to instantiate the dojo grid widget in the `postCreate` property and not in the `constructor`. The reason being the domNode will not be ready uptill that point.

Comment: I saw that the buttons are also not working. I put the construct post but do not know how to put the MyWidget var = new MyWidgetClass (). It's like the dojo did not think the divs, is because of that? Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you need to write you code in the postCreate function.

Simplest way would be to replace the *constructor* keyword with *postCreate*.
The reason being that the *"target-node-id"* will not be available until the postCreate function call.

```
postCreate: function(){
   this.inherited(arguments);
   // Rest of your code here.
   alert("X");
   ...

}
```